# How to implement asynchronous inside d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to change the color of the circles after a period of time. I tried to use setTimeout, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to solve the problem?

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", "10")
                .attr("fill","lightblue")

circles.attr('fill',function(){
            setTimeout(function(){return "red"},2000)
         })
```

Comment: Set the timeout around the fill, returning inside the fill, not the timeout.

Comment: The second argument of the `attr` method, when a function, runs immediately. Also, do not use `setTimeout` at all: the idiomatic solution is just using a *transition*.

Answer (score 2):

[Gerardo's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049149/how-to-implement-asynchronous-inside-d3#comment100625795_57049149) explains why using setTimeout in the way that you did does not work and presents the alternative approach of using d3.transition.

[StackSlave's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57049149/how-to-implement-asynchronous-inside-d3#comment100625439_57049149) explains how to correctly use setTimeout to solve the problem.

See the example below for approaches to solving your problem.

```
const data = [10, 15, 20, 30, 35];

const radius = 10; // px
const yPos = 35; // px

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", radius)
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
     return `translate(${(i+1) * 3 * radius}, ${yPos})`; 
   })
   .attr("fill", "lightblue");

// using setTimeout
setTimeout(function() {
  circles.attr("fill", "red");
}, 2000);

// using d3
circles
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .ease(() => 0) // disable fading
  .style("fill", "red");

// using d3 - recommended (see Gerardo's comment below)
circles
  .transition()
  .duration(0)
  .delay(2000)
  .style("fill", "red");
```

Checkout the [d3.transition docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition) to learn more.

Comment: You don't need to mess with the eased time, which we normally call `t` in D3 lingo, for disabling the transition from blue to red (your *"// disable fading"* comment), just use `duration(0)` and set the `delay` to the value you want, like `delay(2000)`. For 2 seconds, that `ease` will run more than 350 times.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, code updated. Thank you for sharing that insight. I don't understand how you came up with the 350 number. According to the docs, "the easing function is invoked for each frame of the animation," so you're saying there are more than 350 animation frames in the 2 seconds duration. How did you estimate the ease callback being called >350 times over a 2 seconds duration?

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't make myself clear: you have to divide that number by the number of circles (5), so you have 350/5 = 70 frames approximately. The function runs once per element per frame. Have a look at the console here and the me how many `hello`s you see: https://jsfiddle.net/z5x26yjg/1/

Comment: 119, which is in line with my expectations if I assume I'm getting ~60 fps.

Comment: In my machine I have between 65-70. So, in your first code, if you put that same `console.log`, you'd see it running 595 times! (119 * 5)

Comment: That makes complete sense. Thank you for clarifying.